# Struggling to understand how this code outputs Euclid algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

I was trying to write the code of Euclids algorithm and I found some code online which works out the greatest common divisor for two numbers entered. Here it is

```
else {
    return gcd(b, a % b);
}
```

However, I don't quite get how it gets me the greatest common divisor. I understand how Euclid's algorithm works on paper but not this.
To my eyes the above code should return the modulus a of b, so if "a" were 1071 and "b" was 462 it would return 147 however the above code returns 21. How does the first b in    `<code>gcd(b, a % b);` affect the output?

Here's the entire code:

```
package algorithms;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Question3 {
    private static Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {


    //simple input statements to get the numbers of the user
    System.out.print("Please input the first number to be worked on= ");
    double a=input.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Please input the second number to be worked on= ");
    double b=input.nextDouble();

    //call the method in which the calculations are done
    double commondiv=gcd(a,b);


    //print out the the common divisor
    System.out.print("The Common Divisor of "+ a +" and "+ b + " is "+commondiv);
    //System.out.print(b);
}
public static double gcd(double a, double b){
    //an if statement will allow for the program to run even if
    //a is greater than b
    if (a>b){
        //if the input b is equal to zero
        //then the input a will be returned as the output
        //as the highest common divisor of a single number is itself
        if (b == 0){

            return a;
        }
        //this returns the greatest common divisor of the values entered
        else{
            return gcd(b, a % b);
        }
    }
    else if (a<b){
        if (a == 0){

            return b;
        }
        else{
            return gcd(a, b % a);
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If a were 1071 and b were 462 it would return the gcd of 462 and 147.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please  See the Following Explanation for iterations :

In first Iteration
a = 1071 and b = 462

1. a >b so
   gcd(b,a % b) which is gcd(462,147)
2. Again a>b is true as a = 462,b = 147 so
   gcd(147,21)
3. a>b is true as a = 147, b = 21 so
   gcd(21,0)
4. a>b is true as a = 21 ,b = 0
   Now b == 0 is true
   return a i.e. 21

Comment: I think I understand now, your comment made me realize that the output can be thought of as returning gcd(b)( a%b). I was thinking of it like gcd(b,a%, b) for some reason!